# Hibernate SQL working slow

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am working on Struts2 with Hibernate. For accessing data from database I am using hibernate. I have used following hibernate configuration

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database</property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>

    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <mapping class="com.templateproject.table.LoginTable" />
    <mapping class="com.templateproject.table.OMRDetailsTable" />
    <mapping class="com.templateproject.table.RejectListTable" />
    <mapping class="com.templateproject.table.SetWiseQuesDetailTable" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And I used following sql query :

```
  String hql = "from OMRDetailsTable omrDetailsTable where omrDetailsTable.bar_code_no not in(select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') and omrDetailsTable.roll_no not in(select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R') and omrDetailsTable.omr_error in('T','U') order by omrDetailsTable.roll_no";

  Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
  List<OMRDetailsTable> result_1 = query.list();      
  Iterator<OMRDetailsTable> iterator = result_1.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()){         
    omrDetailsTable  = (OMRDetailsTable) iterator.next();   
    set_no = omrDetailsTable.getSet_no().toString();
    try {
      String queryques = "from SetWiseQuesDetailTable setWiseQuesDetailTable where setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm='A' order by setWiseQuesDetailTable.sl_no";

      Query query1 = session.createQuery(queryques);
      List<String> ansDetailsList = new ArrayList<String>();
      List<SetWiseQuesDetailTable> result_2 = query1.list();          

      for(SetWiseQuesDetailTable setDetails : result_2) {
        System.out.println(setDetails.getQa());
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

This is one class here which I mapped :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="reject_list")
public class RejectListTable {  
  @Column(name="centre_code")
  private int centre_code = 0;

  @Id  
  @Column(name="roll_no")
  private String roll_no = null;

  @Column(name="rej_status")
  private String rej_status = null;

  @Column(name="error_type")
  private String error_type = null;

  public int getCentre_code() {
    return centre_code;
  }

  public void setCentre_code(int centre_code) {
    this.centre_code = centre_code;
  }

  public String getRoll_no() {
    return roll_no;
  }

  public void setRoll_no(String roll_no) {
    this.roll_no = roll_no;
  }

  public String getRej_status() {
    return rej_status;
  }

  public void setRej_status(String rej_status) {
    this.rej_status = rej_status;
  }

  public String getError_type() {
    return error_type;
  }

  public void setError_type(String error_type) {
    this.error_type = error_type;
  }
}
```

But when I executed the above code its working too slow. I don't know why may be I am missing something because I am very new in 'HIBERNATE'. When I executing the above code without hibernate then it's working fine.

For extra information :
`OMRDetailsTable`  have 15000 records and `SetWiseQuesDetailTable` have 300 records.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide the mapping class configuration to see how you have mapped them using hibernate?

Comment: You're not using anything from result_1 in the inner query. Then what is the purpose of looping result_1?

Comment: I used data from result_1 but I just removed the code because it was too long.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info and then supply the missing information

Comment: If used the above program without hibernate the same query working fine and performing well but when switched to hibernate then performing too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You must try use JPA. Using criteria you can obtain the data with cascade.

Comment: Is there any other way to do that? Can you provide me some example?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to tune you sql query.

Here is what I suggest and you can tune it further

Original query plan:

```
explain
select * from OMRDetailsTable omrDetailsTable 
where omrDetailsTable.bar_code_no not in(
    select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable 
    where rejectListTable.rej_status='R'
) and omrDetailsTable.roll_no not in(
     select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable 
     where rejectListTable.rej_status='R'
) and omrDetailsTable.omr_error in('T','U') 
order by omrDetailsTable.roll_no;

                                                   QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=53.73..53.73 rows=1 width=154)
   Sort Key: omrdetailstable.roll_no
   ->  Seq Scan on omrdetailstable  (cost=36.02..53.72 rows=1 width=154)
         Filter: ((NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND ((omr_error)::text = ANY ('{T,U}'::text[])))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on rejectlisttable  (cost=0.00..18.00 rows=3 width=58)
             Filter: ((rej_status)::text = 'R'::text)
         SubPlan 2
            ->  Seq Scan on rejectlisttable rejectlisttable_1  (cost=0.00..18.00 rows=3 width=58)
             Filter: ((rej_status)::text = 'R'::text)
  (10 rows)
```

Modified query plan:

```
explain
WITH RejectList(roll_no)
AS(
   select roll_no from RejectListTable rejectListTable where rejectListTable.rej_status='R'
)
SELECT * from OMRDetailsTable omrDetailsTable WHERE NOT EXISTS(
select 1 from RejectList rl 
where omrDetailsTable.bar_code_no != rl.roll_no AND omrDetailsTable.roll_no != rl.roll_no
) and omrDetailsTable.omr_error in('T','U') 

                                                            QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Anti Join  (cost=18.00..33.79 rows=3 width=154)
   Join Filter: (((omrdetailstable.bar_code_no)::text <> (rl.roll_no)::text) AND ((omrdetailstable.roll_no)::text <> (rl.roll_no)::text))
   CTE rejectlist
     ->  Seq Scan on rejectlisttable  (cost=0.00..18.00 rows=3 width=58)
           Filter: ((rej_status)::text = 'R'::text)
   ->  Seq Scan on omrdetailstable  (cost=0.00..15.50 rows=4 width=154)
     Filter: ((omr_error)::text = ANY ('{T,U}'::text[]))
   ->  CTE Scan on rejectlist rl  (cost=0.00..0.06 rows=3 width=58)
(8 rows)
```

As you can clearly see the cost of second query over first. The first query has two table scans on reject table which is reduced to one table scan in second query.

Comment: Am I missed anything in the hibernate configuration file?